# Is this data significant?

Tags: r, statistical-significance

Here is the data frame:

```
structure(list(time = c("Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 0", 
"Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 1", "Day 1", 
"Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 1", 
"Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", 
"Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", 
"Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", 
"Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2"), count = c(1L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 59L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 54L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 207L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 11L, 2L, 1L), cluster = c("C", 
"C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "D", "D", 
"D", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "B", "C", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A")), row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm comparing Day 0 with Day 1 and 2. Clusters A and B are not present at day 0, does that mean that there is statistical significance between day 0 and day 1/day 2 for these clusters? (since when I try to calculate a value using wilcox.test nothing happens).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is likely one of the following two:

1. Is there significant difference in the numerical column across days, controlling for the groups A, B, C, D?
2. Is there significant difference in each group's occurrence across days, controlling for the numerical column?

In the first case, you can run an ANOVA to test the hypothesis.

In the second case, you can run logistic regression to predict each one-hot group column to see if the days and the numerical column has significant effect.

Note that there may be issues with outliers, namely the row with 207. You can argue if the rows with 50+ are outliers or not. It depends on the context.